# MaxPermSize=2048m and yet I get "GC overhead limit exceeded at "

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, robolectric-gradle-plugin

I'm running the gradle of an existing android-studio project and get an error of lack of memory.

even though i have this in my gradle properties:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m
```

I'm using mac

[image]

this is the error:

```
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug
warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
(org.apache.tools.ant.Diagnostics$1) that doesn't come with an
associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
indicate that it is *not* an inner class.


UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.bitSetFromLabelList(SsaMethod.java:137)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaBasicBlock.newFromRop(SsaBasicBlock.java:161)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.convertRopToSsaBlocks(SsaMethod.java:173)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaMethod.newFromRopMethod(SsaMethod.java:103)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.SsaConverter.convertToSsaMethod(SsaConverter.java:44)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:98)
    at com.android.dx.ssa.Optimizer.optimize(Optimizer.java:72)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.processMethods(CfTranslator.java:297)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate0(CfTranslator.java:137)
    at com.android.dx.dex.cf.CfTranslator.translate(CfTranslator.java:93)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:729)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:673)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.access$300(Main.java:83)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main$1.processFileBytes(Main.java:602)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processArchive(ClassPathOpener.java:284)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.processOne(ClassPathOpener.java:166)
    at com.android.dx.cf.direct.ClassPathOpener.process(ClassPathOpener.java:144)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processOne(Main.java:632)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:505)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMultiDex(Main.java:334)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:244)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_77.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 3
```

Comment: What OS are you using and what is the power of your machine?

Comment: Why do you increase the PermSize when you are out of normal heap space?

Comment: I add RAM printscreen. I didn't add `PermSize` it was in the project before me

Comment: Under what version of JVM you are trying to run the application?

Comment: Add `-Xmx2G` to your java argument list and reduce the `MaxPermSize` to a more reasonable value. If that does not help, parallel builds can cause the problem. Did you set the `org.gradle.parallel` flag?